# Get jest JavaScript error handling test to pass and ensure correct error code (malformed URL vs not found URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, jestjs

I am trying to get the following the second Jest test to pass. See below:

```
JavaScript
//app.test.js file

//1st error test fails
 it.only("Should return http status code 400 when passed malformed query",()=>{
    return request(app).get(`api/animals??!${diet}=omnivorous`).expect(400).then(({body})=>{
      const {err} = body
      expect(err.message).toBe("HTTP 400 error: bad request for endpoint")

    })
  })

//2nd error test passes
  it.only("Should return http status code 404 when particular diet for bird does not exist in the dataset",()=>{
    return request(app).get(`/api/animals?${diet}nectivorous`).expect(404).then(({body})=>{
      expect(body.message).toBe("HTTP 404 error: path cannot be found")

    })
  })
```

When I run the tests for the second test that fails it says     expected 400 "Bad Request", got 404 "Not Found". Isn't api/animals??!${diet}=omnivorous a bad request so shouldn't it be status code 400 not 404.

Here is my app.js file that describes the error handling functions that get called within app.use(). Notice that I am passing the error down and using conditional statements to check the status code

```
  JavaScript
//app.js
const handleBadRequest = (err,req,res,next)=>{ 
    if(err.status === 400){
    res.status(err.status).send({message: 'HTTP 400 error: bad request for endpoint'})  
    }else{
    next(err)
    }
  }
  const handleNotFound = (err,req,res,next)=>{   
    if(err.status === 404){
      res.status(err.status).send({message: 'HTTP 404 error: path cannot be found'})  
    }else{
    next(err)
    }
  }

  const handleServerError = (err, req,res,next) => {
    res.status(500).send(err.message)
  }

  app.use(handleBadRequest)
  app.use(handleNotFound)
  app.use(handleServerError)
```